# How to unmount RAM partition from tmpfs?

Tags: server, 18.04, mount, ram, nginx

Some months ago I had installed FastCGI on ubuntu 18.04 nginx server. After that, I served FastCGI cache from RAM. For that, I mount the Ram partition using `tmpfs`.

```
# first - I used this command:
$ nano -w /etc/fstab

# Second there I added this line
tmpfs /etc/nginx/cache tmpfs defaults,size=100M 0 0
```

Now I want to unmount that partition. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to permanently remove that, you can just edit `/etc/fstab` and remove the offending line. But i think that you might be asking for something different.

If you want to remove that partition temporarily (until next reboot or remount) you can try `sudo umount /tmp`. However, you may run into problems, since that location is undoubtedly being used by some applications (see `sudo lsof |grep /tmp`).

Two solutions that i can think of are:

`sudo umount -l /tmp`, this should succeed right away, but all the applications that already use the old hierarchy will still be able to do that. Eventually, when no application will use old hierarchy the directory will be completely unmounted. Keep in mind that it is only at that eventual time (if it is ever reached) that you will recover your 100MiB of memory.

`sudo umount -f /tmp`, this will probably succeed, but in the process will break any application that is currently relying on the files being available. If you will get something horrible happening, you have been warned.

Comment: Thanks, friend. All done! Actually, Before I  edited /etc/fstab and there I removed that line. But still it was reflecting in ram partition.(df -ah | grep tmpfs)                                              Then I reboot the server and it id done.

Comment: Yes, `fstab` is used at the start. Once it is mounted it is "just there". If you think that my answer is helpful, you can accept it.